# is $G(x) = |x-2|$ one to one OR onto?

Tags: functions, elementary-functions

Please help me determine if $G(x) = |x-2|$ is one to one or onto.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/xQWVb) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: In particular, asking whether a function is one-one or onto (NB: "one to one" generally means both $1-1$ and onto) makes sense only when the domain and codomain ("range") are identified.  What domain is function $G$ understood to be defined on?  For example, a Reader could easily make sense of the formula as applying to all complex numbers.

Answer (score 3):

**HINTS**

1. Write down the definitions of from where and to where is $G$ supposed to map. I will assume $G:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ but this is not necessarily true.
2. *Onto* means $G$ maps to every point of $\mathbb{R}$. Note that $G(x) \ge 0$, what can you conclude?
3. $1-1$ means that $G(x) = G(y)$ if and only if $x = y$. Well, $G(x) = G(y)$ means $|x-2| = |y-2|$. Does it follow that $x=y$?

Comment: 1 - it is not mentioned where is G supposed to map , but your assumption is accepted

Comment: 2- I can conclude that it is not onto , right ?

Comment: 3- I conclude it is 1-1 , Right ?

Comment: @user283411 why can you conclude it is 1-1? why do you think it is not onto? add some details.

Comment: I need to know the answer , if i know the answer i wouldn't have asked !

Comment: @user283411 you can deduce the answer from my hints, directly -- that's the reason i gave you the hints. I would like you to think about the problem yourself, not have me tell you what the answer is.

Comment: Oh okay , I see that it is not onto as the results are always from 0 to infinity , so all the negative numbers have no images , right ?

Comment: And I think it is not 1-1 because if we supposed that X = -2 the result is 4 , and if X = 6 the result is also 4 , so F(-2)=F(6) , is that true ?

Comment: @user283411 excellent, this is exactly right

Comment: Thank you so much , I would like to ask other questions , how can I mention u ?? @gt6989b

Comment: @user283411 you can ask others, there is lots of good people here. You can also tag the question in the comments like you did with your previous one, using the @ symbol